Help needed for compiling the LP solver CLP on COIN-OR
I am having some issues with the CLP project on COIN-OR. If I try to compile the C++ code (on Visual Studio 2022) downloaded from the CLP repository (https://github.com/coin-or/Clp), I get multiple compilation errors related to the missing class 'AbcSimplexProgress'.
It seems that there is no file named 'AbcSimplexProgress.cpp' in the CLP package. Does someone have any pointers on how to fix this issue?

This sounds similar to a closed bug report from last year. Are you using the cmake file to compile CLP?

Thanks a lot @prubin, I was compiling the code using Visual Studio on a Windows machine. Let me compile using cmake as this bug report suggests. Thanks again!
